# Extract financial data from yfinance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, yfinance

**Problem:** I have to extract data based on different asset classes such as Bonds, Commodities, Listed Options, Cryptocurrency, etc. I am able to get the financial data from `yfinance` if and only if I know the ticker symbol and it is a manual process and not based on the asset class.

**Example (Hard Coded):**

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

cryptocurrency = ['BTC-USD', 'ETH-USD', 'USDT-USD', 'BNB-USD', 'XRP-USD', 'ADA-USD', 'HEX-USD', 'SOL-USD', 
                  'AVAX-USD', 'LUNA1-USD', 'DOGE-USD', 'DOT-USD', 'DOT-USD', 'SHIB-USD', 'MATIC-USD']

cryptocurrency_df = yf.download(cryptocurrency, period = '1y')
cryptocurrency_df.dropna(inplace = True)
```

Through this, I am able to get the desired result but being hard coded I am able to extract only a few of the available options.

**Relevant Link:** Through this source: https://finance.yahoo.com/cryptocurrencies/ we can see all the listed cryptocurrencies. I want to extract data of the say top 25 cryptocurrencies based on the market cap.

**Request:** It would be better if the help is provided not using web scraping libraries because I need data to be in the form of:

```
             Adj Close   Close      High        Low         Open        Volume
             C1   C2...  C1  C2...  C1  C2...   C1  C2...   C1  C2...   C1  C2...
Date   
YYYY-MM-DD   PAC1 PAC2   PC1 PC2    PH1 PH2     PL1 PL2     PO1 PO2     PV1 PV2
```

---

```
where C1, C2 ... are the cryptocurrencies
      PAC1, PAC2 ... are Adj Close of the cryptocurrencies, and so on
```